# On changing a value of const variable through implicit access to it via void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering if I could change the value of a const variable implicitly through a pointer. The example I came up with is the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  const int const_num = 10;
  printf("const_num value: %d, const_num address: %p\n", const_num, &const_num);

  void* ptr = (void*)&const_num;
  printf("ptr value: %p, ptr reference value %d\n", ptr, *(int*)ptr);

  *(int*)ptr = 20;
  printf("ptr value: %p, ptr reference value %d\n", ptr, *(int*)ptr);
  printf("const_num value: %d, const_num address: %p\n", const_num, &const_num);

  return 0;
}
```

The answer is that **NO**, you cannot change the value of a const variable whichever way you choose. But the behavior of the output is what bugs me. The output of the previous program is the following:

```bash
const_num value: 10, const_num address: 0x16af26db8
ptr value: 0x16af26db8, ptr reference value 10
ptr value: 0x16af26db8, ptr reference value 20
const_num value: 10, const_num address: 0x16af26db8
```

So, despite the fact that `const_num` keeps its initial value, the object in the same memory address (`0x16af26db8`) the pointer references has transformed from `10` to `20`. Is there a viable explanation for this, or it is considered *undefined* behavior?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. The compiler is told the value can never change, so it's free to make optimizations accordingly. That includes where to store the value (if anywhere) and when to load it (if ever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if I could change the value of a const variable implicitly through a pointer.

The C standard does not prohibit you from trying, and you may or may not succeed.

When a program attempts to modify an object defined as `const`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, because C 2018 6.7.3 7 says:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined…

That does not mean you cannot try. With static objects (any object declared outside a function or with `static`), an attempt is likely to fail with a memory access violation because modern general-purpose multi-user systems commonly put static `const` objects in memory marked read-only for the program.

With objects defined on the stack (automatic storage duration), the system is unable to mark the memory read-only because the stack is used for both `const` and non-`const` objects. Even if a separate stack were made for `const` objects, it could not be marked read-only for the program because the program has to initialize automatic `const` objects each time a function is entered. So, each time a function with `const` objects is entered, the program would have to mark the `const` stack as writeable, initialize objects on it, mark the `const` stack as read-only, and proceed with the function. This would add considerable overhead to the program.

So, typically automatic `const` objects are in memory you can modify. However, if you modify the memory of a `const` object, that does not mean your program will behave as if the object was modified! That is because the compiler optimizes your program and does not always get an object’s value from memory.

In the case of an object defined with `const`, the compiler knows the program behavior is only defined if the object is not modified. It knows it is allowed to behave as if the object is never modified. Thus, when your program executes `printf("const_num value: %d, const_num address: %p\n", const_num, &const_num);`, the compiler does not have to generate code that loads `const_num` from memory. Instead, what effectively happens is the compiler can reason “I do not need to load `const_num` from memory, because I know it was initialized to 10, and I am allowed to assume it does not change. So I can just use 10 for the argument to `printf`.”

So the compiler generates code that passes 10 to `printf` without loading the value of `const_num` from memory.

Comment: `volatile const` will be read

Comment: @gulpr: That is not guaranteed. It would happen in a program with behavior defined by the C standard. However, if an attempt is made to modify an object defined as `const`, even one that is `volatile`, the entire behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. The C implementation would no longer have an obligation to read the memory of a `volatile` object.

Comment: I did not say modify. volatile const are guaranteed and it commonly used to define memory mapped read only hardware registers

Comment: @gulpr: Re “I did not say modify”: OP did. That is what the question is about. The question is about attempting to modify a `const` object, through a  pointer. The question and this answer are not about reading a `const` object generally but about what happens in a program that attempts to modify it. Re “volatile const are guaranteed”: No, they are not, in this circumstance. In a program with defined behavior, accessing a `volatile const` is guaranteed to access memory. However, if an attempt to modify `const` object is made, all guarantees are nullified.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is explicitly spelled out in section 6.7.3p6 of the [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
> const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
> type, the behavior is undefined.** If an attempt is made to refer to an
> object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
> with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

So no modifying a `const` object via a non-`const` pointer.

Comment: 6.7.3 6 of the C standard says that qualifiers are idempotent and may appear with `_Atomic`. The rule that attempting to modify a `const` object is not defined is in 6.7.3 7. C 2011 is not the C standard.